# Join for two select statements?

Tags: mysql, join, nested

I have two SQL tables called A and B.
A has the form

**`A=(uniqueIdentifierA,uniqueIdentifierB, id, columnC, columnD)...`**

B has the form

**`B=(idA,idB).`**

Now I get the two values **`uniqueIdentifierA`** and **`uniqueIdentifierB`**. Both values belong to one unique id of table A. 
This id is used as a **`foreign key in table B`**.

Now I would like to check if there is a dataset in column B, which contains the id for **`uniqueIdentifierA as idA`** and the id for **`uniqueIdentifierB as idB`**.

What is the most elegant way to solve this request? Is there a way using a Join without a nested **`SELECT statement`**?

Example data for column A:
**`(userA,xiejfalifjeij,2,...)`** 
**`(userB,39388skjjflie,3,...)`** 
Example data for column B:
**`(2,3)`**

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you provide table structure, sample data, tried query and expected results.

Comment: I know that it could work with a SELECT statement inside ON part of a Join. But I would like to avoid a nested SQL Statement. Example Data will be added.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.uniqueIdentifierA=B.idA AND A.uniqueIdentifierB=B.idB
```

Above query can help you.

Comment: This can not work, because uniqueIdentifierA is something like a username and idA is an id (number). idA is a foreign key of Table A.